# Degrees of freedom ANOVA table for regression

Tags: regression, anova, degrees-of-freedom

I've calculated the following ANOVA table for a linear regression in R:

```
anova(lm(mpg ~ drat, mtcars)) 


Analysis of Variance Table

Response: mpg 
Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F) 
drat 1 522.48 522.48 25.97 1.776e-05 *** 
Residuals 30 603.57 20.12 
---
```

I'm wondering how the degrees of freedom for the residuals are calculated. I can see it is n-2, but why minus 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $n-2$ because you have fitted the intercept and a slope for `drat`. Generally, if you have $p$ predictors and the intercept, the degrees of freedom for the residuals are $n-p-1$ (with $n$ being the sample size). The degrees of freedom are the sample size minus the number of estimated parameters. [This document](http://www.massey.ac.nz/~mbjones/Book/Chap9.pdf) provides a nice annotation for the ANOVA table in `R` (from page 21 onwards).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601422/what-should-be-the-degree-of-freedom-in-anova-table can you please look in to this question also ?