# What should be the degree of freedom in ANOVA table

Tags: anova, degrees-of-freedom, cluster-sample

Consider the area under wheat for a sample of 44 clusters
selected from 11 different villages. Four clusters were selected from each of the
11 villages and each cluster consists of 8 survey numbers(fields). Here sum of
squares (SS) due to between villages is 2000, SS due to between clusters within
villages is 8250 and Total SS is 30000. Write the ANOVA table.

My approach

```
| source of variation  | degrees of freedom  | 
| --------             | --------------      |
| between the villages | 11 -1 = 10          |
| between the clusters | 4-1 = 3             | 
| error                | (11-1)(4-1)         |
| total                | 44-1= 43            |
```

Now my doubt is that each cluster consists of 8 survey numbers,  then there should be some interaction of clusters and survey numbers
How to incorporate that in degree of freedom ?

Comment: Here the question says the unit of measurement is field , so total degree of freedom should be 11*4*(8-1) ?

Comment: There are a few ways to calculate degrees of freedom for clustered/hierarchical designs. Kenwood-Rogers, Satterthwaite, and Between-Within come to mind. They all have different considerations for the level of the exposure of interest. If you randomize whole clusters, for instance, between-within is the most conservative.

Comment: @adamo hey , actually I have just completed my undergraduate course in Statistics and I am aware of only between within in anova  , and most probably this question also needs only that much information,  So can you tell how to use only that much knowledge and tackle this question ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct distribution of degrees of freedom is

| source of variation | degrees of freedom |
| --- | --- |
| between the villages | 11 -1 = 10 |
| between the clusters | 11(4-1) |
| error | 308 |
| total | 44*8 -1 |

This is the case of two way anova with m observations per cell